# How do I start a Windows 10 partition on a MBR partitioned disk on a system that otherwise uses GPT/UEFI GRUB?

Tags: grub2, uefi, gpt, mbr, grub2-mkconfig

Okay, let me explain. This is a UEFI computer. It has two disks. The primary disk is partitioned with GPT and boots via GRUB2 to an Arch Linux partition. The secondary disk is partitioned with MBR and only boots if I disable the primary disk in the UEFI setup utility. The secondary disk has a partition with Windows 10. My question is how do I add a menu entry to the primary GRUB2 configuration that boots the Windows 10 partition on the secondary disk?
I tried `grub-mkconfig` with `os-prober` and it was unable to find the Windows 10 install. There's apparently nothing wrong with the Windows 10 install, since it boots just fine on its own.
I then tried manually adding various menu entries to the grub.cfg but they didn't work. Below are some of the entries that I tried.

```
menuentry "Windows 10 (loader) (on /dev/sda3)" {
    insmod part_msdos
    insmod ntfs
    insmod ntldr

    ntldr (hd0,msdos3)/bootmgr
}

menuentry "windows 10 (loader) (on /dev/sda3) 2" {
    insmod part_msdos
    insmod ntfs
    chainloader (hd0,msdos3)+1
}

menuentry "Windows 10 (loader) (on /dev/sda3) 3" {
    insmod part_msdos
    insmod ntfs
    chainloader (hd0,msdos3)/Windows/Boot/EFI/bootmgfw.efi
}
```

The most successful one is the last one which apparently boots to the EFI FW program but gives a BCD error (which is not present when booting normally.)

Comment: AFAIK you can't boot a legacy Windows if booted from UEFI. But you could [convert](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/81502-convert-windows-10-legacy-bios-uefi-without-data-loss.html) your Windows disk to GPT.
Make sure to backup your Windows drive and maybe disconnect your primary disk before you run the conversion (haven't tried that with a dual boot system and two disks). `grub-mkconfig` should find Windows after the conversion.

Comment: UEFI & BIOS are not compatible. Once you start booting in UEFI, you cannot switch to BIOS without rebooting. BIOS & UEFI Windows partitions, note system has totally different format  & meaning between BIOS & UEFI
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/dn898504%28v=vs.85%29.aspx & 
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/configure-uefigpt-based-hard-drive-partitions#RecommendedPartitionConfigurations
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/dn898510%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#RecommendedPartitionConfigurations

Answer (score 2):

You cannot boot Windows installed in MBR mode from UEFI. Period.

You will have to

1. Grab Windows UEFI boot files somewhere, unpack them to `/boot/efi/EFI/Microsoft/Boot`
2. Recreate `BCD`
3. Remove all the entries from `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\System\MountedDevices`

This will probably make your Windows bootable.

Answer (score 1):

##### Minimal Work example

My System:

```
/dev/sda has a old windows 10 install on a MBR partition table
/dev/sdb has a gpt layout with grub and arch
--/dev/sdb1 efi system partition (esp) --this should be your main esp
```

Usually if you boot into windows, the windows boot manager looks up the beginning of the windows partition in the MBR. If you want to boot from grub uefi you need the corresponding uefi boot entry that specifies the beginning of the windows partition.

##### Generating UEFI boot file

Since windows is on MBR there currently is no such file. To generate it you can use bcdboot[[1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/bcdboot)] in cmd. Make sure you have your main esp (here the arch efi system partition) mounted in windows (here we mount \dev\sdb1 on the letter X e.g. windows disk management tool or diskpart in cmd[note1]. Notice that \dev\sdb**1** is used NOT the disk /dev/sdb)

```
bcdboot C:\Windows /s X: /f windows-uefi
```

In this example we use bcdboot[1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/bcdboot) to take all relevant boot information regarding our windows partition (C:\Windows) and generate a file called windows-uefi (/f windows-uefi) containing all that information on the drive where our efi system partition is located X (/s X:) See [[1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/bcdboot)] for reference.

note1: of course you can generate that file anywhere you like an copy it afterwards. Its interesting that os-prober searches through all efi system partitions. Thats why it can find a windows gpt/uefi install on the first hand.

##### updating grub

Since your on arch, there is no update-grub as in debian. You have to do it manually using:

```
# grub-mkconfig -o /boot/grub/grub.cfg
```

if you have your config file in the standard location. See the [archwiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/GRUB) for further details and edge cases. Make sure you have os-prober running. Once more consult the wiki to ensure it. It should detect the windows-uefi file we created earlier and add it to the boot entry.

note2: the # implies you need elevated privileges so execute with sudo or - if you know what you are doing - as root.

##### Anecdote

When I got myself a hardware upgrade I searched for this method since I was to lazy to reinstall windows. It has been working like a charm ever since. The best part: Now I'm *allowed* to install windows 11 since windows detects it has been booted in uefi-mode even though its still a MBR install xD

###### sources

1. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/bcdboot
2. https://askubuntu.com/questions/447686/how-to-boot-windows-8-from-a-legacy-mbr-partition-in-uefi-mode-via-grub
3. https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/GRUB
4. https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/GRUB#Windows

Answer (score 0):

UEFI leads to GRUB, then GRUB finds the Windows partition and loads the Windows loader program. So, in theory, even if the Windows is MBR, it should still work because GRUB doesn't use MBR, GRUB directly locates the loader program in partition C.

Try not to use hd0, but this:

search --set=root --fs-uuid 12345678-1234-1234-1234-1234567890

ntldr /bootmgr

use the real uuid after --fs-uuid

In windows command line use this to find uuid

wmic volume get Driveletter, DeviceID

Comment: It's not about locating the loader. The problem is, the `/bootmgr` of a BIOS-bootable modern Windows is still a 16-bit executable, similar to a DOS `*.com` executable. You can verify it using the `file` command. If Secure Boot is in effect, when GRUB uses an UEFI system call to read it into memory, UEFI detects it is not a signed UEFI binary and marks the memory block as non-executable by the CPU. Even if Secure Boot is disabled, the 16-bit BIOS calls `/bootmgr` uses are simply not available in UEFI mode, and it will fail as soon as the UEFI-mode GRUB attempts to execute it.